# Constructor tries to call copy constructor, virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, virtual-inheritance

I had a hard time articulating a proper title.

```
struct Base
{
    Base(int) {}
    virtual ~Base()=default;
};

struct Derived: virtual public Base
{
    Derived(float, int): Base{1} {}
    Derived(Derived const&)=delete;
    ~Derived()=default;
};

struct Comp: private Derived
{
    Comp(): Base{1}, Derived{1.0f, 1} {}
};
```

This gives a compiler error:

```
x.cc: In constructor ‘Comp::Comp()’:
x.cc:16:34: error: use of deleted function ‘Derived::Derived(const Derived&)’
  Comp(): Base{1}, Derived{1.0f, 1} {}
                                            ^
x.cc:10:2: note: declared here
  Derived(Derived const&)=delete;
  ^~~~~~~
```

Why would the copy constructor be requested here? The problem disappears when I get rid of the virtual inheritance (and accordingly the `Base(int)` call in `Comp`'s initializer list).

This is on `gcc version 6.2.1 20161124 (Debian 6.2.1-5)`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, was a little inconsistency because I simplified the example further.

Comment: Post a real [mcve]. Including compiler and version if the code really fails to compile.

Comment: What are you expecting the `Base{1}` to do in the constructor of `Comp`, given that `Comp` is not derived from `Base`?

Comment: @juanchopanza This is a minimal, complete and verifiable example... But I added the compiler version.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `Base` is a virtual base of `Comp`. So its constructor has to be called in the most derived class.

Comment: @TFM Interesting. Clang has no problem with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in GCC. Both Clang and GCC 7 [accept the code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/f9tZxwf4hxNylH6N).